How should I reinstall bathtub drain when there is a gap with the pipe
The bathtub drain in the new house that I moved in wasn't smooth so I decided to open the drain and give it a good cleaning!
There was a screw in the middle of the drain valve that I opened but when the drain valve completely detached, I noticed that the pipe inside the tub pulled down and now wasn't easily high enough to re-attach it back to the drain valve and I don't have a good grip to pull it up and screw!
Somehow need to pull it up to be able to screw it back to the drain valve. Sending some picture hopefully it makes it clear!
This is the image of the drain. The screw in the middle is not long enough to reach to the pipe without pulling the up

This is the image of the pipe inside the bathtub. It has a distance to hole where I can attach it to the drain

Any idea how to do this?

What is underneath?  Can you get a loop of rope/wire around it to pull up?

underneath looks like a hollow space, I tried a lot with rope, wire, adhesive tape. no luck!

Next time if all you want to do is clean the drain, don't disassemble it!  buy a $1 disposable plastic drain snake, about 18 inches long, remove as much hair as you can with that (slowly and gradually so you don't get a huge glob of hair stuck on the snake that is too big to pull through the cross-piece), and follow up with a chemical drain cleaner.  That's usually good enough.  Not always, but you do that before you take the drain apart!

You or a plumber is going to have to get under there and push it back into place.
If that means cutting a hole in the ceiling below, that's what it means. Or you come in through the wall around the tub.
That connection should only be removed when you are planning to remove the tub as well, normally. It's often a royal pain to get to. And there's good odds that by disturbing it a leak may start, which you won't know about until it's leaked for a while if you can't make access to the space. Some seal with a gasket, some with sealant (you appear to have a gasket.)
New leak might happen there, might happen at the other end of the pipe that hasn't been moved since the tub was installed.
If the installation was done in a fashion that does not make access reasonable, you'll be faced with unreasonable choices, such as removing the whole tub (gets worse if the area is tiled) to get at it. But usually you can hack through a wall to get there - unfortunately modern builders don't normally provide access panels, so if the wall is tiled on the other side, it will be a mess. If you cut a nice neat hole the size of an access panel you can add one. Having installed a few tubs, I would not think of unscrewing that without first verifying reasonable access to it.
Depending on how the white plastic around the nut is formed, exactly (can't tell in picture) you MIGHT be able to put a small J hook on a long stiff wire (coathanger wire typical) to hook under one of the "blades" supporting the central nut, and pull it up, threading the top of the drain over the wire. You'd want to check very carefully for leaking when the tub is used at the floor, and anywhere below if there is space below.

thank you for the reply! This is what I was trying to make myself believe that's not going to be needed! :'( I don't understand all the previous tubs that I saw it was easy to open and reattach the drain valve!
Some risk of leakage, I agree but it still feels like with some kind of a grip it should be able to pull the thing up.

I agree with this answer, and I hope you can access through the ceiling below because ceilings are relatively easy to patch.  I'd like to add that 1) If the pipe is stubbornly pulling away from the drain, you really should not try to repair it from above, and 2) If you've come this far, you really should replace all the rubber parts, or just buy a whole new drain kit, because they have a lifespan and you can install one that allows you easier access to snake the drain without dislocating it this way.

Hi guys, as an update, I didn't go this way. I used 2 hooks (more specifically 2 allen drivers.  in fact finding the possibility of using allen was like a moment of divine intervention!) once find the right size and right angle, it was truly effortless to align and reinstall the pipe to the drain

Take some pictures of how you did it and post an answer. Self-answering is perfectly fine here, and it might help the next person.
